# Laravel using groupBy in with relationship doesn't work properly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, group-by, laravel-8

Probably my mistake but i couldn't realize where my mistake is.

I have customer model which has `schedule_registers()` relation

```
public function schedule_registers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ScheduleRegister', 'customer_id', 'id');
}
```

I also have ScheduleRegister model which has `teacher()` relation

```
public function teacher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'teacher_id', 'id');
}
```

I get data in CustomerController like this (i don't use `->get()` because i'm sending this data to datatable);

```
$customer_index = Customer::with([
    'company',
    'schedule_registers',
    'schedule_registers.teacher',
]);
```

This query gives me that output;

https://jsonblob.com/915606370225766400

and when i try to use group by teacher_id and change query to this;

```
$customer_index = Customer::with([
    'company',
    'schedule_registers.teacher',
    'schedule_registers' => function ($q) {
        $q->groupBy('schedule_registers.teacher_id');
    },
]);
```

output turns to this;

https://jsonblob.com/915605962518446080

In brief, when i try to use groupBy, i doesn't get any error, but get wrong output. If you could check outputs, when i use groupBy, some `schedule_registers` data becomes empty but some doesn't.

What is the right way to use `groupBy` in that situation?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by adding the `groupBy`?

Comment: @Rwd i'm trying to achieve get schedule_registers grouped by teacher_id. for example if i have 2 records in schedule_registers table with same teacher_id, i want only one of them

Comment: You are trying to run `groupBy()` on a separate query. Including relations by the `with()` method does not join the related tables in, it queries them afterwards. I would suggest get a collection with `get()` and then do grouping on the collection.

Comment: try ` ->groupBy(['schedule_registers.teacher_id']);`